# jQuery validation class

Tags: jquery, validation, class

I'm looking for some nice jQuery validation class, where I could add some custom validation functions and where I will be not forced to rely on inputs classes, where I could define my validation rules with an object or some array.

Could you recommend me some validation classes you are using?

Comment: Sorry, what was the question?

Comment: This is what you need http://elclanrs.github.com/jq-idealforms/

Comment: Something different from http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation#API_Documentation ?

Comment: @Barmar I cant see any download link in there...

Comment: Click on "Back to the jQuery Validation plugin page" and it takes you to the main page, which has a download link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what I use in my projects:

https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine#readme

and very happy with it, check it out.

Comment: Found it few seconds ago `:P`, I havent much experience with github yet.

Comment: I'am receiving strange error after loading the scripts on my project, firebug console says: `jQuery.validationEngine rules are not loaded, plz add localization files to the page `

Comment: did you include the local js file? like <script src="js/jquery.validationEngine-en.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

Comment: yeah it seems like I didnt included none of the language files. It works now. Maybe you know; is there a posibility to change the "tool tip" style and position? I would like to position it on the top of the invalid input.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include language file, for example:

https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine/blob/master/js/languages/jquery.validationEngine-en.js

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.9.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate-1.12.0.js"></script> <!-- from http://jqueryvalidation.org/ -->
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validationEngine-en.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validationEngine.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" ></script>
```